# SearchView is invisible with collapseActionView parameter since 24.1 design library

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview, androiddesignsupport

I encountered a problem since I updated the Android Design Library from 23.4.0 to 24.1.1

My SearchView was defined like this :

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/title_action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    />
```

But my SearchView input became invisible (I can write in it, but the text, or hint does not appear).

I described it in the following picture with 3 different steps :

[image]

If I remove the "collapseActionView" parameter, it works fine, but the searchInput is only half of the screen (instead of full width).

Do you know if there was a change in this library which could explains it ?

Thanks by advance ! (And sorry for the image quality...)

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I copied your issue and post in Android issues https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218417

Comment: This is annoying. Same issue here. It seems the only solution for now is to use API23.

Comment: For your information @palmsnipe, I removed collapseActionView action. It is not the exact same behavior, but searchView is visible

Comment: I did the same thing @RémiP, it works ok on a project with an empty toolbar, but it's not good if the toolbar includes a picture for example. The search view will be on the top.