# Invisible Text in SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-appbarlayout, android-search

I've the following layout for an `Activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_charts_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- App bar -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <!-- Toolbar -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Overlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <!-- Tab layout -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white_80" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- View pager -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

With *App.Theme.Overlay*:

```
<style name="App.Theme.Overlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/App.Theme.SearchView</item>
</style>
```

And *App.Theme.SearchView*:

```
<style name="App.Theme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="submitBackground">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

The *menu actions* for the `Activity` consists in a `SearchView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/search"
        android:title="@string/search_a_product"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

When i click the search icon and type some text, I assume it has the same color of the background, because i cannot see it, but the I've search results. This is not happening if the `SearchView` is not inside the app bar (but I need it). Could you please provide some help with this? Many thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583430/searchview-is-invisible-with-collapseactionview-parameter-since-24-1-design-libr ?